# How do I embed JSX in javascript?

Tags: reactjs

Given

```
  <td className="myColumnStyle">
    {data.value}
  </td>
```

and

```
value: '(<input type="text" value="1" />)'
```

This outputs literal text.  I want HTML.  How do I enforce the value to be interpreted as JSX as opposed to literal text?

Answer (score 0):

I simply removed the quotes and it worked:

```
value: (<input type="text" value="1" />)
```